# How to write KOMA scrttl2 subject without the words "Subject: " in front?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

The standard way of adding a subject is by using

```
\setkomavar{subject}{Insert the subject of the letter}
```

in the preamble of the document. This inserts a line of text before the opening of the letter as follows.

> **Subject:** Insert the subject of the letter

However, I would like to have the subject without the words "Subject: ". Also, I would like to have the subject line in bold, as shown below.

> **Insert the subject of the letter**

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For removing "Subject: " you are looking for `scrlttr2`'s option `subject=untitled`, whereas for the bold font `\setkomafont{lettersubject}{\normalcolor\bfseries}` should do the trick. However, as those two are the defaults, you should probably look in your document where you changed them.

```
\documentclass[foldmarks=true,foldmarks=blmtP,
  fromphone,fromemail,fromlogo,
  subject=untitled,
  version=last]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\setkomavar{fromname}{Joe Public}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{2 Valley\\
  SAMPLEBY\\
  ZY32 1XW}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{0\,12\,34~56\,78}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{joe@public.invalid}
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedright
  Club member no.~4711\\
  since 11.09.2001\\
  chairman 2003--2005}
\setkomavar{date}{29th February 2011}
\setkomavar{place}{Sampleby}
\setkomavar{subject}{Missing general meeting}
\setkomafont{lettersubject}{\normalcolor\bfseries}
\begin{letter}{%
    Joanna Public\\
    1 Hillside\\
    SAMPLESTEAD\\
    WX12 3YZ%
  }
  \opening{Dear Madam Chair,}
  The last general meeting was more than a year ago.
  I would like to remind you that the articles of our
  club stipulate that one should be held every
  six months. For this reason, I call on the executive
  board to arrange such a meeting immediately.
  \closing{Anticipating an invitation}
  \ps PS: I hope you do not take this request amiss.
  \setkomavar*{enclseparator}{Enclosure}
  \encl{Excerpt from the articles governing general
    meetings}
  \cc{executive board\\all members}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]